# Where to paste sqlite DB into iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, nsdocumentdirectory

I've just been handed over an app with pretty vague instructions of how to update an internal sqlite DB.

In the past, I've done this with `Cordova` by just replacing an existing `sqlite` db into `/www/` dir.

I also created a `SwiftUI` project using `FMDB`. I believe the code itself would automatically create a non-existing DB in app's Documents Directory. My code to modify the DB would then just modify this same DB in that same location. I never formally replaced the DB itself.

Anyways, instructions given to me for this app are to simply replace the DB (just a copy and paste of the `.sqlite` file) into the Project's root directory. This is literally just using `Finder` and copying and pasting. However, I don't seem to be getting the new data.

Should I be doing this in Xcode? I.e. 'Adding new file by right-clicking. Should I then copy file to project and/or add to target?'

I'm not sure this 'copy from Finder to project dir' is actually right. Quick glance at code shows that it is attempting to read DB from app's documents directory.

Is there a way to actually copy the DB to the app's documents directory?

Note: I noticed while building the app that it says something like "Copying db.sqlite to app". So that indicates to me that perhaps there's some kind of build rule that copies from the project Dir to the app's Documents Directory.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try searching... google returns many results for `swift copy file from bundle to documents` -- this is probably what you want: https://gist.github.com/rd13/320b3fed4d5f10ab8ea833b3f9818980

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your DB to your project's structure by dragging it or **File->AddFiles** with selecting copy to  project target

After that in your code you can read it like this

```
let db = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "sqlite")
```

And  since you can't do any update operations to main bundle then you should copy  this file to your document's folder the first time  app launches , then read it from  there any upcoming launch